# Assigning jQuery function to variable doesn't work, but wrapping it does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code that, depending on circumstances, should either look at the entire page, or else only within a certain part of it.  So I originally had some code like this:

```
var doSearching = wholePage ? $ : $('#portion').find;
var target = doSearching('#someSelector');
```

After some debugging, I realized this was a problem, and taking an educated guess ended up with something along these lines:

```
var doSearching = $;
if (!wholePage)
  {
    doSearching = function(selector) {return $('#portion').find(selector);}
  }
var target = doSearching('#someSelector');
```

Well, that works OK, but I don't really understand what's going on that the first snippet is wrong but the second is correct.

What's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's going wrong is that `find` relies on the value of `this` during the call to `find` (to know what it's looking within), but in your code, you're calling it directly, and so `this` during the call will be the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode), not the jQuery instance that `find` expects it to be.

You could do this:

```
var portion = wholePage ? null : $('#portion'); // Or: `var portion = wholePage && $('#portion');` if you like
var doSearching = portion ? portion.find.bind(portion) : $;
var target = doSearching('#someSelector');
```

That uses [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) to ensure that when you call `doSearching`, `find` is called with `this` referring to the jQuery object resulting from `$('#portion')`, and so it knows what to search within.

It's basically a slightly more concise form of your "wrapping" example, but passes through all arguments rather than just one.

---

`Function#bind` is an ES5 feature missing on old browsers like IE8, but can be polyfilled if supporting them is important.

Comment: The most readable form is probably just do use a ternary like `$( wholePage ? document : "#portion" ).find( selector )` and avoid bind entirely imo, but +1 for correctness!

Comment: @dherman: Yeah, in my own code it would probably be `var target = wholePage ? $(selector) : $("#portion").find(selector);`, but... :-)

Comment: Well, this is a reduced sample to demonstrate the problem... in reality it is a lot longer and uglier than this so the single ternary wouldn't quite get it.  Using document as a selector isn't a bad suggestion, though.